# Aptana connection error

Tags: connection, aptana, sftp

I have a problem with a SFTP connection on my project.

I succeed creating the connection (The Test button told me all was ok)
And i can browse through de folders of the connection.
I can upload my local files to it

But, i can't download files from it.
From the logs :

```
!ENTRY com.aptana.syncing.core 4 0 2012-02-15 11:39:59.821
!MESSAGE (Build 3.0.0.1321920947) [ERROR]  Error during sync {0}
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.aptana.filesystem.ftp.internal.BaseFTPConnectionFileManager.getCanonicalURI(BaseFTPConnectionFileManager.java:103)
at com.aptana.core.io.efs.VirtualFile.toCanonicalURI(VirtualFile.java:215)
at com.aptana.core.io.efs.VirtualFile.toString(VirtualFile.java:230)
at com.aptana.core.io.efs.SyncUtils.copy(SyncUtils.java:89)
at com.aptana.ide.syncing.core.old.Synchronizer.downloadAndDelete(Synchronizer.java:827)
at com.aptana.ide.syncing.core.old.Synchronizer.download(Synchronizer.java:711)
at com.aptana.ide.syncing.ui.actions.DownloadAction$1.run(DownloadAction.java:146)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I can download files in SFTP from this server via Filezilla
I had several project with the same organization( Debian server, SFTP connection, ..), it always worked well

Any ideas ?